# What is the best high-capacity local storage option for a web app?

Tags: web-applications, jquery-mobile, local-storage, indexeddb, web-sql

I'm building a web app using jquery mobile that will have lots of images that need to be cached for offline access, and I'm looking for the best way to accomplish this.

I originally was just going to create a cache manifest file for the images, but there are too many, and they exceed the size limit. I also considered Indexeddb, but it doesn't seem to have much support yet.

The solution needs to work for both Android and iOS and also be accessible in a web browser. Total storage capacity will probably need to be around 15-20 MB. Is there a good option for this?

Also, I don't have much experience with web apps, so any examples you could provide would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web sql database (sqlite) will give you 50MB local storage and works in Android and iOS
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage
There is a nice library that simplifies access to sqlite here 
https://github.com/jhubert/javascript-sqlite

Comment: this is not and will not be supported in firefox by mozilla, but may be supported via third party wrapper libraries on top of indexedDB: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/06/beyond-html5-database-apis-and-the-road-to-indexeddb/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any good solution for this. Even if you use and combine multiple storage methods (including the standard browser cache) you still won't get near to 15MB.

I fear this is going to come down to a choice between a dedicated app, and not storing the images locally.